# connecting a function to a frame in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

Is there other way or techniques to connect a function into the frame rather than using Connect() and EVT_-macros?

here is a sample of connect event:

```
Connect(ID_Quit, wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
(wxObjectEventFunction) (wxEventFunction) (wxCommandEventFunction) &MyFrame::OnQuit);
Connect(ID_About, wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
(wxObjectEventFunction) (wxEventFunction) (wxCommandEventFunction) &MyFrame::OnAbout);
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use them? These two are the choices I know provided by wxWidgets. One is for static linking at compile time (EVT_ macros) and the other is to dynamically link the handlers during the program's execution (Connect())

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of wxWidgets (2.9.0+) then you can also use [wxEvtHandler::Bind](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a84b1e446053bda8f76f13336839e8b64) which is a more flexible version of `Connect`. You can see more information about `Bind` [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind).